# What is good about Intel Vt-d technology for direct IO?

Tags: virtualization, intel

I'm interested in **[2 CPUs](http://ark.intel.com/compare/71460,71459)** ( or I should APUs ? ) the main difference between this 2 units it's the presence of a Vt-d feature that Intel names "Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d)".

Since I'm also interested in running virtualized environment on this machine, what kind of features I will get or miss in real world scenarios ? What this Vt-d is about ?

Comment: This is primarily for type 1 hypervisors (bare metal).  So ESXi, HyperV, Xen, KVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [excellent Intel blog post](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/06/25/understanding-vt-d-intel-virtualization-technology-for-directed-io) which is at the top of the google results for `vt-d`:

> VT-d, at the time of this writing, includes four key capabilities
>
> 1. I/O device assignment. This feature allows an administrator to assign I/O devices to VMs in any desired configuration.
> 2. DMA remapping. Supports address translations for device DMA data transfers.
> 3. Interrupt remapping. Provides VM routing and isolation of device interrupts.
> 4. Reliability features. Reports and records system software DMA and interrupt erros that may otherwise corrupt memory of impact VM
>      isolation.
>
>    Note that VT-d is not dependent on VT-x. That is, a VT-x enabled
>      system can operate without VT-d, or without VT-d enabled or
>      configured. You simply miss the benefits of the feature. Many people
>      have asked about this point.
>
>    You can read about VT-d in detail at:
>
>    http://www.intel.com/technology/virtualization/technology.htm?iid=tech_vt+tech

[This link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/intelligent-systems/intel-technology/vt-directed-io-spec.html) is the architectural spec for VT-d, if you have an afternoon to burn and really want to know how it works.

Comment: an application like qemu will benefit from this ? It's also a technology that works only if it's supported by the BIOS ? right ?